# Counting graphs with fixed V+E

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'd love your help with this question.

Let $n\geq3$ be a fixed integer. How many non-isomorphic graphs with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges are there where $V+E=n$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there will be any kind of useful formula for this?

Comment: This is very hard for fixed $p$ and $q$, and $n$ isn't a particularly natural parameter here.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A120412

Comment: FWIW, this was also posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68017/counting-graphs

Comment: Might a starting point be to think about how many planar connected graphs there which obey this condition?

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/how-many-2-edge-colourings-of-k-n-are-there) shows how to compute the generating function of non-isomorphic graphs on some number of nodes by the number of edges. The answer to your query is obtained by extracting the relevant coeffcients from these generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

This type of enumeration can be achieved using Polya Theory to attain a generating function. The best reference is Riordan, http://books.google.com/books?id=zWgIPlds29UC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false, page 129. See page 143 for the application to counting graphs by |E| and |V|.

If would like to construct such graphs , there is a C program "nauty" developed by Brendan D. McKay, based on his math article http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/pgi.pdf.