# Number of non-isomorphic connected graphs with m edges.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This might be an easy one, but I cant figure it out.

Given $m$ edges how many connected (non-isomorphic) graphs can be drawn. Ofcourse there are no loops, multiple edges etc.

I tried the recurrence method but introduction of cycles complicate it. Also for a given value of $m$, I might calculate the number of such graphs using sage, but I needed an expression.

Am I missing some obvious counting technique?

Comment: I doubt there is a single nice formula for this, see [oeis:A002905](http://oeis.org/A002905).

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks for the info.

Comment: Here is a [MSE Post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/how-many-2-edge-colourings-of-k-n-are-there) that shows how to calculate these values and presents some context and background material.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact formula for this. The closest you can get is to use a program like [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/) to compute the number of graphs for specific values of the number of vertices and edges.

**Example.** Computing the number of non-isomorphic connected graphs with $9$ vertices and $13$ edges.

> foo@darkstar:~$ geng -c 12 13:13 -u
>
> 28908 graphs generated in 0.11 sec