# creating all possible connected graphs with $n$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

Inspired by [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105207/how-do-you-arrange-six-6-ohm-resistors-to-have-a-total-resistance-of-6-ohm) on Electronics, my question is: **what is an algorithm for creating all possible graphs with a given number of edges but a possibly varying number of vertices?**

There is at least one [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477958/number-of-non-isomorphic-connected-graphs-with-m-edges) dealing with enumerating how many such graphs exist, but none that I could find that explained an algorithm for actually generating them.

Because I'm not a mathematician, an explanation that doesn't require more than the relatively elementary level of graph theory I remember from university would be most useful.

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected? Weigthed or unweighted? Do you allow cycles?

Comment: The graph is undirected and edges are weighted.  Cycles are definitely allowed.  The resistor question is one application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is surely computationally difficult. There are probably better algorithms, but here's a brute-force approach:

Generate all trees on $v$ vertices for each $v \in \left[\displaystyle \left \lceil \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+8n}}{2} \right \rceil, n+1\right]$ (the min and max possible number of vertices for a simple graph on $n$ edges). You can do this iteratively - begin with a single vertex and add one edge at a time in all possible ways. Then for each tree on $v$ vertices, add $n-v+1$ edges to it, one at a time in all possible ways. You can check for isomorphisms among the generated graphs at each step (see [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/)).

If you are simply looking for a practical way to generate these with the least amount of effort, you could just use geng, which comes with nauty to generate these.

Comment: If you going to usenauty, why not just use geng (which comes with nauty) and the graphs directly?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil True, though I'm not sure "use geng" really addresses the question, and I don't think the questioner necessarily wanted all the details for an algorithm to check isomorphisms (which is necessary in any algorithm that generates all non-isomorphic graphs on $n$ edges). Added your comment about geng to my answer though.

Comment: I found that the [paper by the authors of nauty](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2013.09.003) describing the algorithm they use was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help!