# Cycle type of induced permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, integer-partitions

Let $m = \binom{n}{2}$ and $S_n, S_m$  be  the symmetric groups,  $S_n  \subset S_m$. Let  $\pi \in S_n$ and let $\pi$ have the the cycle type  $[λ_1,λ_2,\dots,λ_k]$, $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+ \cdots+\lambda_k=n$ where  $λ_i$ is the  length of $i$-th cycle. $\pi$ induces a permutation $\pi^\prime$ in $S_m$ by permuting the set of pairs $\{ \{i,j\}\ |\ i,j \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}\text{ and } i \neq j \}$. We may ask what is the cycle type of $\pi^\prime$ considered as element of $S_m$?
For arbitrary permutation we may calculate the cycle type of the corresponding induced permutation  by hand. For example, let $n=4,m=6$, and a permutation $\pi \in S_4$  have the cycle type $[2,2]$. Then after some direct  calculation we get that the induced permutation in $S_6$  has  the cycle type $[2,2,1,1].$

**Question.** Is there any effective algorithm for calculating the cycle type of the induced permutation?

Comment: I don't think your usage of cycle type matches your definition, as a permutation with two $1$-cycles and two $2$-cycles can't be in $S_4$, nor can a permutation in $S_6$ have a $3$-cycle and a $4$-cycle.  Perhaps you mean "$\lambda_i$ is the length of the $i$-th cycle"?

Comment: yes, corrected..

Comment: Also you aren't going to have $n$ cycles, usually (you use $n$ for two different things in the above -- maybe use $k$ for the number of cycles?)

Comment: well.. the idenity permutation is considered as $n$ cycles  $(1)(2)\cdots(n).$

Comment: True, but all other permutations will have fewer cycles.  Using $n$ for the number of cycles implies that the number of cycles will always be $n$, which is not the case.  Better to use a different variable for potentially different numbers.

Comment: I have edited your question to clarify it based on the comments.  Let me know if it is not correct.

Comment: @ universalset..Yes,  that is correct.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **every unordered pair of distinct cycles** in $\pi$ of lengths $\lambda$ and $\mu$, we get $\gcd(\lambda, \mu)$ cycles of length $\text{lcm}(\lambda, \mu)$ in $\pi^\prime$.  These correspond to the orbits of $\{i,j\}$, where $i$ is in the first cycle and $j$ in the second, under repeated application of $\pi^\prime$.

For **every cycle** in $\pi$ of length $\lambda > 1$, we also get the permutations of the pairs of elements from that cycle.  All cycles in $\pi^\prime$ thus obtained have length $\lambda$, except when $\lambda$ is even, and in that case exactly one cycle (the orbit of $\{1, 1+\frac{\lambda}{2}\}$ if we assume that the cycle is $(1, \ldots, \lambda)$) has length $\displaystyle \frac{\lambda}{2}$.  So from this cycle of length $\lambda$ we get $\displaystyle \left\lfloor \frac{\lambda-1}{2}\right \rfloor$ cycles of length $\lambda$, and an additional single cycle of length $\displaystyle \frac{\lambda}{2}$ if $\lambda$ is even.

Combining these should give you an effective way of computing the cycle type of $\pi^\prime$ given the cycle type of $\pi$.

Comment: @universalset..I need some time to undestand and check it. But thank you anyway.

Comment: By the way, there is another way to phrase the question (and answer) in terms of group actions:  We're looking at the action of the group $\langle \pi\rangle$ on the set $\{\{i,j\}\ |\ i, j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\text{ and } i\neq j\}$.  The results I mention can then be derived by careful application of the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Comment: What you are describing is the cycle structure of the edge permutation group of the complete graph on $n$ nodes induced by vertex permutations from the symmetric group. There is a discussion of how the cycle structure of the induced permutation can be computed efficiently and some relevant Maple code at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/how-many-2-edge-colourings-of-k-n-are-there).

Comment: I have found the answer on my question in Harary,Palmer book, page  84