# How can you find the total number of non-isomorphic unlabeled graphs with n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I have seen some questions about labeled graphs, but no answers for an unlabeled graph. I calculated for the first four graphs and it seems to be $2n-1$ total graphs for $n$ vertices. I'm not sure if this holds for all possible graphs however. Is there a way to show this?

Comment: I believe it's an extremely open problem, see [here](https://oeis.org/A000088). Also, check your formula against the list there :)

Comment: The following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/) might prove interesting reading.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got to your 2n-1 result, as there are 11 graphs on 4 vertices! Also note that there are different numbers for connected and disconnected. A000088 is disconnected, and A001349 is connected.